# why cin.get(char, int) don't overflow?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    const int size = 10;
    char test[size];
    char test2[size];

    cout << "the size of test is " << sizeof(test) << endl;

    cout << "input a sentence:" << endl;
    cin.getline(test, 50);

    cout << "your input is: " << test << endl;
    cout << "the size of test is " << sizeof(test) << endl;

    cout << "-----stop-----" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I tested it in Clion with **MinGw-w64 3.1**, the result like this:

```
the size of test is 10
input a sentence:
this is a very long sentence
this is a very long sentence
your input is: this is a very long sentence
the size of test is 10
-----stop-----

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

It didn't stop until I finished all my output. Shouldn't it stop the moment I try to read the array test? After all, I claimed size 10, but tried to read size 50.

Then I tested this under Ubuntu with **gcc 5.4.0**, it didn't give out any error message! I wonder why it did't stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are (un)lucky!

Here is what I got:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
the size of test is 10
input a sentence:
this is a very long sentence
your input is: this is a very long sentence
the size of test is 10
-----stop-----
Abort trap: 6
```

What you are witnessing is undefined behavior, which means that it's undefined what will happenn when your code executes.

Comment: seems you are right......I tested it again with others' computer, results are different. Some go wrong, some go right......But it stops at the end at all windows environment.